# ifstream and ofstream not working after crash

Tags: c++, clion

I was trying out c++ for the first time and thought I'd make a small program that just prints out lines from a file. I am using the Clion IDE and everything was working fine and it worked. Then out of no where my computer freezes and when I try to run the code again the ifstream doesn't seem to open. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
    int main() {
        ifstream file("hello.txt");
        cout << file.is_open() << endl;
        string line;
        while(getline(file, line)) cout << line << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I've tried reinstalling cygwin(might not have done it correctly, don't know) and Clion but to no help.

Edit: tried compileing the code through a website and it worked but when I run it on my machine the file doesn't open.

Edit 2: Clion was playing tricks on me and changed the working directory, after setting it again everything works fine. Solved

Comment: Perhaps you don't have write permission to the file or its directory. Try changing the filename , and/or outputting the failure code (`errno` might have it; otherwise call `GetLastError()` from `<windows.h>`). Code 5 means Access Denied.

Comment: It was Clion playing tricks on me, it for some reason changed the working directory to NULL. Well fixed now.

Answer (score -2):

```
    //Don't forget to include fstream
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
       ifstream file("hello.txt");
   if(file.is_open())
   {
    string line;
    while(!file.eof())   //while  we  are not  yet  to  the end  of the  file 
       { 
         getline(file, line)
         cout << line << endl;
       }

   }
   else 
       cout<<"File  not opened \n";


  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I had included fstream, only forgot to copy the whole file.

Comment: ` while(!file.eof())` is the wrong way to read a file.  `getline` should be in that `while`.

Comment: `file.eof()` doesn't mean "we are at the end of the file"